# Form within form + angular5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am new to Angular part, I am trying to achieve Dynamic forms(form within form).

What I am trying to achieve is.

[image]

When the plus button  is clicked the sub-dropdown part should add, And if i clicked `Add another Mapping` the while single box should appear.

My HTML file:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
   <form [formGroup]="attrForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(attrForm)">
      <div formArrayName="schemaAttr">
        <div *ngFor="let address of attrForm.controls.schemaAttr.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <span>Schemas {{i + 1}}</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="attrForm.controls.schemaAttr.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeschmeAttr(i)"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <ng-select [items]="configuredSchema" [closeOnSelect]="true"  bindLabel="name" placeholder="Choose a schema" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedschema1">
            </ng-select>   
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
              <ng-select [items]="configuredSchema" [closeOnSelect]="true"  bindLabel="name" placeholder="Choose a schema" (change)="onChange2($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedschema2">
            </ng-select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
            <form [formGroup]="addattrForm" novalidate>
              <div formArrayName="addAttr">
                <div *ngFor="let attribute of addattrForm.controls.addAttr.controls; let i=index" class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <select [(ngModel)] ="selectedattribute1">
                     <option *ngFor="let attribute of attributes1" value={{attribute}} >
                        {{attribute}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <select [(ngModel)] ="selectedattribute2" >
                     <option *ngFor="let attribute of attributes2" value={{attribute}} >
                        {{attribute}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="margin-20">
                    <a (click)="addAttr()" style="cursor: default">
                    +
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>                
          </div>

      <div class="margin-20">
        <a (click)="addschmeAttr(addattrForm)" style="cursor: default">
         Map Another schema +
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="margin-20">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!attrForm.valid">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

But im not getting the right output, If i clicked `Add Another Mapping` option the previously mapped dropcount is appearing as empty sub-dropdown, Please suggest some better ideas to achieve this.

Comment: add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: @Chellappan I cant add all my code to `stackblitz.com` since its confidential.. Can you share some ideas what can i do to acheive this,. Good if you provide some sample code

Comment: please don't use both [tag:angularjs] and [tag:angular] tags unless your project is truly a multiple framework project.  **These are not the same framework**.

Comment: @Claies Sure.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand what you want for your sub-dropdown's plus button. However for "Add another Mapping":

```
//In your HTML
<div class="box" *ngFor="let array of myArray">
  <p>
    <label for="firsName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="textarea"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="firsName">Second Name:</label>
    <input type="textarea"/></p>
  <p>
    <label for="firsName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="textarea"/>
  </p>
</div>

// Change the field as per your requirement.

<button (click)="addMoreBox()">Add More</button>
<button (click)="removeBox()">Delete Box</button>

// In your controller/Typescript.
  myArray = ['122'];


  addMoreBox() {
    this.myArray.push('something got push');
  }

  removeBox() {
    this.myArray.pop();
  }
```

The Key idea here is to make use of *ngFor.

**IMPORTANT**

For the example, i am just push a string in the array, however in your case, i believe you should insert something important to keep track of mapping.

[You can play here for more.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyaq8m)

Answer (score 0):

While I would try to give a better and more elaborate response, I feel I can't do better than this project does
https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I would suggest to work according to this amazing example created by https://stackblitz.com/@rahulrsingh09 It's kept fairly simple and easy to understand.

It's a beautiful example for nested forms and the reason I managed back then to create my own dynamic and nested forms.